# NSPredicate: Unable to parse the format string

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have written the below predicate but it crash down the application and reason is `'Unable to parse the format string "(rootActivityId IN 12,13 AND (activityType == 3 OR activityType == 2)) OR (activityId IN 12,13 AND (activityType == 3 OR activityType == 2))"'`

```
let activityTypeClause = "(activityType == \(NSNumber(integer: ActivityType.TypeTwo)) OR activityType == \(NSNumber(integer: ActivityType.TypeOne)))"
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(rootActivityId IN \(activityIds) AND \(activityTypeClause)) OR (activityId IN \(activityIds) AND \(activityTypeClause))")

// activityIds contains coma separated string
```

I am not able to figure out where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation for IN:

> Equivalent to an SQL IN operation, the left-hand side must appear in
>   the collection specified by the right-hand side. For example, name IN
>   { 'Ben', 'Melissa', 'Nick' }. The collection may be an array, a set,
>   or a dictionary—in the case of a dictionary, its values are used.

That suggests that the comma-separated string should actually be a collection object.  Whether it needs to be a `NS`-style collection of a Swift one isn't clear to me.

Not commenting on whether it works as a predicate, but the following does not give me a parsing error:

```
let rootActivityId = "12"
let activityIds = ["12", "13"]

let pred = NSPredicate(format: "rootActivityId IN %@", argumentArray: [activityIds])
```

Comment: Since `NSPredicate` is almost certainly still Objective-C probably the author needs, regrettably, to use the predicate-intended printf-style format for building his predicate. No string interpolation. And then Swift collection to Objective-C collection mapping should just work. This are my reactions upon reading this, the already correct answer.